# How do I name a new directory (dir.ceate) using a value in R

Tags: r, directory

I have a loop that outputs a new value for "a" and I want to create a new directory to output the results of the proceeding analyses which use the value for "a".

```
a <- 1
dir.create("D:/Tests/a")
setwd("D:/Tests/a")
```

How do I write it so that the value of "a" is used as the name of the new directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
a <- 1
p = file.path("D:/Tests", a)
dir.create(p)
setwd(p)
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use `paste0`:

```
a <- 1
dir.create(paste0("D:/Tests/", a))
setwd(paste0("D:/Tests/", a))
```